# MeteorJS How to set the "from" field for the accounts emails such as verify email/reset password

Tags: meteor, mandrill

I am trying to send "verify email" emails from my deployed meteor app (at digital ocean Ubuntu 14.04) via Mandrill and the willio:mandrill package. After deployment, I am able to send an email from my app on startup using the Mandrill API.

```
Mandrill.messages.send({
   message: {
      "text": "Greetings from example.com!",
      "from_email": "demo@example.com",
      "from_name": "Keith - example.com",
      "subject": "App Started",
      "to": [
          { email: "ggg@gmail.com", name: "Keith" }
      ]
   }
}, function( error, response ) {
   if ( error ) {
      console.log( error );
}  else {
      console.log( response );
   }
});
```

This email sends so I know I have my MAIL_URL set and am able to access my mandrill account from the application. However, when I try to get an account-tied email such as verify email or reset password, it does not send. I believe this is because I am unable/dont know how to set the "from" field of email like I am with the above code. However I imagine that it could also be because of something else so here is the code that alters what the verifyEmail email looks like.

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.subject = function(user) {
    return 'Activate your new account';
}
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html = function (user, url) {
    var result;
    try {
        result = Mandrill.templates.render({
            template_name: 'verify-email',
            template_content: [
                {
                    name: 'CONFIRMURL',
                    content: url
                },
                {
                    name: 'FNAME',
                    content: user.username
                }
            ],
            merge_vars: [
                {
                    name: 'CONFIRMURL',
                    content: url
                },
                {
                    name: 'FNAME',
                    content: user.username
                }
            ]
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while rendering Mandrill template', error);
    }
    return result.data.html;
}
```

How would I be able to set the from field or otherwise fix the verify email through mandrill?
BTW, I was using this guide for help but still havent been able to fix the issue. https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/sending-email-with-mandrill/

Comment: I don't know if this will solve your problem, but you can set the from field like so:

Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.from = function(user){return 'Keith - example.com <demo@example.com>';}

Answer (score 1):

This is how I setup email in my app:

```
  Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = Meteor.settings.public.siteName;
  Accounts.emailTemplates.from = Meteor.settings.public.emailFrom;
```